# webservice security exception

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

for work i need to make a webservice that gets information from sharepoint lists, i found a function on the internet that should do it, but i get a security exception

System.Security.SecurityException: request of the permission of type System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 failed.

anyone knows how to fix this? trust level is high so that's not it. i've been searching for couple of days now on the internet and can find a thing.

```
code:
        [WebMethod]
            public string GetListItems()
        {
            String sResult = "";
            WS_Lists.Lists listService = new WS_Lists.Lists();
            listService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");

            listService.Url = "http://ws-0622/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

            System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

            string listName = "{B476DFD7-37F1-4FE8-BCCB-41B3DA87FF8C}";
            string viewName = "{7137FFF8-48FF-4C69-8C76-0E3BBD1EA7F9}";
            string rowLimit = "150";

            System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
            System.Xml.XmlElement viewFields =
                xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
            System.Xml.XmlElement queryOptions =
                xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");

            query.InnerXml = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />" +
                "<Value Type=\"Counter\">3</Value></Gt></Where>";
            viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />";
            queryOptions.InnerXml = "";

            System.Xml.XmlNode nodeListItems =
                listService.GetListItems
                (listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, null);

            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode listItem in nodeListItems)
            {
                sResult += listItem.OuterXml;
            }

            return sResult;
        }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: what's the function you found? What kind of service are you running ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh134614%28v=office.14%29.aspx
Enjoy

Comment: im trying to run a C# Webservice the code is added in the post.

Comment: Is your webservice is on the same server where you are accessing sharepoint list?